# Unable to extract the data from the Nested JSON path

Tags: json, rest, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to API automation. Here is my JSON structure. I want to extract the "LunId" from all the 3 arrays. Path is mentioned in the code.

[image: JSON structure1]
[image: JSON expanded structure1]

Error1:

[image: When using "$" in the code]

Error2:

[image: When not using "$" in the code]

```
@Test

public void getAllLuns(){   

Response resp = given().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+"ddnsdndnn22x");
                when().
                get("http://10.100.242.11/api/v1/luns");

String Name =  resp.                
               then().
               contentType(ContentType.JSON).
               extract().
               path("$..LunId").toString();

System.out.println("Lun Name is--->"+LunId);
```

I am extracting the correct data in JSON path Extractor online, but while running it in eclipse it gives me an error. Problem is in the path. Please help, how to work with these kinds of paths.
Getting Error1- when using"$" in the path and Error2 when not using it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Peter Haddad

Comment: The error is thrown is because the LunId is accessed from Array. Instead, save the JSON Array and iterate over it to get the value of  LundId.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done using JSONPath Lib

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

```
   public List<String> getLunIDNames() {

    return lunIDNamess = JsonPath.read("ValidJSON", "$..LunId[*].Name");

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't get it how to use it in my code. Can you please help

Comment: You need to parse your response as a String where it says "ValidJSON" followed by a valid JSONPath.
Alternativel send your JSON response on pastie.io

Comment: Thanks. What to do, If I have to get the whole JSON response as a list, then get the dictionary at 0th location from that list and then extract a certain element from it.      e.g. if JSON response has {0} and {1}. Both has an element say,"Name". How to get {0}.Name

Comment: You can get them as a List or A String using a JSON Path like $..LunId[0].Name.
Alternatively you can get the name based on index toString

Comment: I can do that but, getting JSON path everytime  is very tedious. I am looking for something by which I get the JSON response as a Java list ans then I can do list operations. I am using Rest assured for API testing.

Comment: Not sure why getting JSON Path everytime will be tedious, as long as there is a response it shouldn't be a problem.
Using the initial JSON path returns all the objects as list

Comment: It's tedious because I have to manually find the correct JSON path and then place it e.g. JsonPath.read(resp.asString(),"$..CapacityAllocation.Name");                    It doesn't work if I pass "$."  in the JSON path to get the all objects as a list.

Comment: You can use an online JSON Evaluator all you need to do is to copy your Response and Paste in here http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: I got this working superbly without getting into JSON path manually.                 

                                                                                                            
       String xyz = response.jsonPath().getList(Id).get(0).toString();                                                This gives me "Id" value at 0th.